# Identifying integers in Excel cell for formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula in cell Y5:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(AVERAGE(D5:D50),0),"#,###")&"mi"
```

which gives the value: `1,923mi`

And this formula in cell Y6:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(CONVERT(Y5,"mi","km"),0),"#,###")&"kms"
```

which gives `#VALUE!`

I am assuming this is because Y6 cannot convert the string `"mi"` to kilometres. Is there a way to tell Excel to just read the integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE(Y5,"mi",""),"mi","km"),0),"#,###")&"kms"
```

(and consider formatting for the inclusion of `mi` or `kms`!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will take only the numbers.

```
 =TEXT(ROUND(CONVERT(left(Y5,len(y5)-2),"mi","km"),0),"#,###")&"kms"
```

If this still doesn't work, you may need to convert the number portion of the text to a value, so it would be:

```
 =TEXT(ROUND(CONVERT(Value(Left(Y5,Len(y5)-2)),"mi","km"),0),"#,###")&"kms"
```